# onExit not working with material ui transition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a snackbar component:

```
const handleExited = () => {
  console.log('exit');
};

const slideTransition = (props) => {
    return <Slide {...props} direction='right' onEntered={handleExited} onExited={handleExited} />;
  };


return (
  <div>
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={3000}
      onClose={handleClose}
      TransitionComponent={slideTransition}
    >
      <div>
        <AlertWrapper severity={snackbarVar()[0]?.severity}>
          {snackbarVar()[0]?.message}
        </AlertWrapper>
      </div>
    </Snackbar>
  </div>
);
```

When a snackbar is shown on the app the `handleExited` method is called through the `onEntered` but when the snackbar is removed the `handExited` method is not called through the `onExited`.

Why does the `onEntered` work but not the `onExited` ?

Comment: i do not see the interface for `Slide` has either `onEntered` or `onExited`. https://material-ui.com/api/slide/

Comment: The docs say "Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element (Transition)." `Transition` does have those props.

Comment: @windmaomao https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4pxil?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: thanks, this codesandbox seems working with `onExited`, i do see the console log message. Is this a browser we use differently?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma, the code sandbox works, but it doesn't use `<SnackBar>` as it was in the question.

Comment: @tromgy I suppose the setOpen from the snackbar could cause the `onExited` on the <Slide> not to happen.

Comment: Here's a working example with `<SnackBar>`: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wlv7i?file=/demo.js but it leaves some questions unanswered -- see the comment in the `SlideTransition` function.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `TransitionComponent` and add `TransitionProps`.

```
<Snackbar
  TransitionProps={{ onEntered: handleExited, onExited: handleExited }}
>
```